Intuitive explanation for the shortest distance between a point on a parabola and a point on a circle.
Consider a parabola $(P)$ and a circle $(C)$ with center $I$ and radius $r$ that doesn't intersect the parabola. Let $M$ be a point on the parabola and $N$ be a point on the circle. Let $A$ be the intersection of $MI$ and the circle. It's clear that $MN \geq MA,$ so MN assumes the minimum value when $N ≡ A,$ in which case $MN = MA = MI - r,$ so $MN$ is shortest when $MI$ is shortest. It happens that $MI$ is shortest when $MI$ and the tangent line at $M$ are perpendicular to each other. I was able to show it algebraically as follows; however, I wonder if there is a more intuitive explanation for why this is the case. Thank you!
$(P): y = ax^2 + bx + c \implies M(x_M, ax_M^2 + bx_M + c)$
$(C): (x - x_I)^2 + (y - y_I)^2 = r^2 \implies I(x_I, y_I)$
$MI^2  = (x_M - x_I)^2 + (ax_M^2 + bx_M + c - y_I)^2 = f(x_M)$
$f(x_M)$ is a quartic function with a positive leading coefficient, so $f(x_M)$ always attains its minimum value at one of its relative minimums.
$f'(x_M) = 2(x_M - x_I) + 2(ax_M^2 + bx_M + c - y_I)(2ax_M + b) = 2(x_M - x_I) + 2[y_M - y_I]y'(x_M)$
If $f'(x_M) = 0$ at $x_M = x_I$ (i.e., $MI ⊥ Ox$), $[(ax_I^2 +bx_I + c) - y_I]y'(x_I) = 0.$ Since (P) and (C) don't intersect, $y'(x_I) = 0.$ Thus, if $f(x)$ assumes its minimum value at $x_M = x_I,$ then $MI ⊥ d: y = y'(x_M).$
If $f'(x_M) = 0$ at $x_M \neq x_I, \frac{y_M - y_I}{x_M - x_I} y'(x_M) = - 1 \implies MI ⊥ d: y = y'(x_M)$


1/ Any tangent to the parabola is a separating hyperplane. Hence, at a point $M^$ whose tangent goes through $I$, $IM^$ is the minimum of all possible $IM$.  $\quad$ 2/ Or another approach: We want to minimize $IM$, from point $I$ draw larger and larger circles until we just touch the parabola. The circle is tangent to the parabola, which means that their tangents at the point are the same line. Hence this tangent (to the parabola) is perpendicular to the radius of the circle.

@CalvinLin Thank you so much!

The Lagrange multiplier method tells you that at a point at minimal distance from the circle, the normal vector to the parabola is proportional to the radius vector from the center of the circle.  Thus the radius vector will be orthogonal to the tangent line of the parabola.

Thank you so much!
